# Why two objects with the same hashcode are not necessarily equals?

Tags: java, hashtable, equals, hashcode

Currently I drilled into the JSE source code for fun. From some tutorials I found a principle `two equals objects (i.e. as to object a and b a.equals(b) returns true) must have the same hashcode, on the other hand, two objects with the same hashcode are not necessarily equals`. According to the HashTable source code of Java API (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java), e.g. refer to line 254, we can almost derive `equals => same hashcode`, but I still can not fully understand why `two objects with the same hashcode are not necessarily equals`. Anyone can give more reasoning on this? Thanks in advance

Note! This question is more interested in why **two objects with the same hash code are not necessarily equals**

Comment: There are more possible `String`s (for example) than there are possible `int`s. Eventually you'll run out of unique hashcodes, even with an otherwise perfect hashing algorithm.

Comment: you and your twin brother have the same birthday day but are different persons....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple matter of counting. A hash code is an integer so has 32 bits. Take now a `Long` for example. Since it is 64 bits long, there are much more values than 2<sup>32</sup>. Hence there must be a lot of values having the same hash code.